# Objective-c: ссылка в VK

Tags: ios, objective-c

Есть ссылка на страницу в VK. После нажатия на кнопку пользователь переходит по ссылке. Ссылка открывается через браузер. Можно ли как-то открывать ссылку через приложение VK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот, только ссылки нужно поменять

```
NSURL *appUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"vk://vk.com/"]; // ссылка для открытия через приложение 
NSURL *safariUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"vk.com/"]; // ссылка для браузера

// если можно открыть через приложение то открываем, иначе через браузер
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:appUrl]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appUrl];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:safariUrl];
}
```